# Take controll over the maximum counts in ggplot2 + geom_bin2d?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with the `ggplot2` and the `geom_bin2d()`-Function. I would like to produce `heatmap-Plots` of the same area throughout different points in time. My problem is that I want to take control over the counts. Is it possible to fix the maximum counts, for example form 0 to 30 (see example). If I plot a new sample with more points, there is always a shift in the counts (in my example from a maximum of 15 to a maximum of 30). In the package `"hexbin"` this is possible by the command "mincnt" and "maxcnt". With "maxcnt=30" I can fix the maximum counts to 30 in both plots. But I don't get it to do this with `ggplot2 + geom_bin2d...` Do you have an idea? I didn't found something about this here or elsewhere. Thanks a lot!

[maximum counts of 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EmTd.jpg)

[maximum counts of 30](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaivE.jpg)

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)
dat1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000))

p1 <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_bin2d(bins=25) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")
plot(p1)

set.seed(2)
dat2 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(2000), y = rnorm(2000))
p2 <- ggplot(dat2, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_bin2d(bins=25) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red")
plot(p2)
```

Comment: I'm not positive if I understand your question entirely, but do you mean just adding limits to `scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high ="red", limits=c(0,30))`

Comment: Sometimes the solution is that simple, that was exactly what I was searching for! Thanks a lot!